# Is your spouse's income based on location?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Once I was married I moved the wife to Whiterun where she opened her shop and feeds me 100 septims a day.  Im wondering if I move her to a different location will she make more money and increase my share from 100 septims.  Does anyone know if the location of a spouse's store makes a difference in income?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not. You will always be awarded 100 gold per day.

Comment: thanks man, cant play right now...due to UFC 139...so im just plotting what i can do better...haha.